# Complex JOIN Query Where JOIN Table May NOT Have Records

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, one called "users" and one called "items". I am looking to compile a list of IDs from users where the field users.eventdate is within 3 days of right now. To make things more complicated I'm also looking to see if items.startingdate is within 3 days of now.

Therefore, if users.eventdate is within 3 days of now or there is an item.startdate within 3 days of now then return the users.ID. The relationship between users and items is users.ggProjectId and items.uID.

I currently have:

```
 $strSQL  = "SELECT users.ID, users.ggProjectId, users.timezone, users.ggTimestamp, users.slug, items.uID
        FROM items
        JOIN users ON users.ggProjectId = items.uID
        WHERE ( users.eventdate <= DATE( NOW( ) + INTERVAL 2 DAY ) 
        AND users.eventdate >= DATE( NOW( ) - INTERVAL 2 DAY )) OR 
        ( items.startingtime <= DATE( NOW( ) + INTERVAL 2 DAY ) 
        AND items.startingtime >= DATE( NOW( ) - INTERVAL 2 DAY ))
        GROUP BY users.ggProjectId";
```

The problem is that if there are no items for the users record then I don't get that as a result even though I need it because the eventdate falls within the time frame. I think it's the JOIN that's killing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data may not exist in the table you want to join with, then you want to use a [`LEFT JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join):

```
SELECT
     users.ID
    ,users.ggProjectId
    ,users.timezone
    ,users.ggTimestamp
    ,users.slug
    ,items.uID
FROM users
LEFT JOIN items
 ON users.ggProjectId = items.uID
WHERE 
    (
         users.eventdate <= DATE( NOW( ) + INTERVAL 2 DAY ) 
     AND users.eventdate >= DATE( NOW( ) - INTERVAL 2 DAY )
    ) OR ( 
         items.startingtime <= DATE( NOW( ) + INTERVAL 2 DAY ) 
     AND items.startingtime >= DATE( NOW( ) - INTERVAL 2 DAY )
    )
GROUP BY users.ggProjectId
```

With `LEFT JOIN`, you will return all rows in the first table (the "left" side), and join the other table based on the key, which may or may not have a match in the "right" side.